# How to find at match between two rows in excel based on multiple criteria, including fitting inside a date range

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

This is busting my chops, I keep losing the rabbit while contemplating the logic necessary to complete this task.  My VBA knowledge is virtually non-existent, so my apologies for not including what I've tried so far.

I have two sheets with 5 columns.  The first sheet contains schedules for future dates.  The second sheet contains same day changes to that schedule. I would like to find instances when the same day change corresponds to a date, ID and color in the original schedule (meaning the the same day change was unnecessary or the schedule was faulty).

Here are the two sheets Schedule Sheet

[image: Schedule Sheet]

and Sane Day Sheet

[image: Same Day Sheet]

Ideally, I'd like to have rows 3 and 6 returned from the Same Day Sheet, or have a "1" in the F column.

I am totally lost and even a kick in the right direction would be a huge help.

Thanks.

Comment: Questions without your existing code will generally go unanswered until you post your code.

Comment: I've seen that in the years lerking around the sit. My apologies, but I truthfully had nothing.  I kept getting lost and deleting everything to start from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This places a "1" in column F; it doesn't work with any error values - generates Type Mismatch errors

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FindConflicts()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim ur1 As Variant, ur2 As Variant, r1 As Long, r2 As Long
    Dim lb1 As Long, ub1 As Long, lb2 As Long, ub2 As Long

    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Schedule")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Same Day")

    ur1 = ws1.UsedRange:    lb1 = LBound(ur1):  ub1 = UBound(ur1)
    ur2 = ws2.UsedRange:    lb2 = LBound(ur2):  ub2 = UBound(ur2)

    ur2 = ws2.UsedRange.Resize(, ws2.UsedRange.Columns.Count + 1)
    For r2 = lb2 + 1 To ub2
        For r1 = lb1 + 1 To ub1
            If ur2(r2, 1) = ur1(r1, 1) Then         'compare columns 1
                If ur2(r2, 2) = ur1(r1, 2) Then     'compare columns 2

                    'compare 1st date in col 4 of ws2, if between col 4 and col 5 of ws1
                    'or      2nd date in col 5 of ws2, if between col 4 and col 5 of ws1
                    If (ur2(r2, 4) >= ur1(r1, 4) And ur2(r2, 4) <= ur1(r1, 5)) Or _
                       (ur2(r2, 5) >= ur1(r1, 4) And ur2(r2, 5) <= ur1(r1, 5)) Then

                            ur2(r2, 6) = 1

                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
    ws2.UsedRange.Resize(, ws2.UsedRange.Columns.Count + 1) = ur2
End Sub
```

---

[image: Same Day]

Comment: Man did that work perfectly.  I can't thank you enough.